# How to use canonical tags with a global header

Tags: php, canonicalization

My website uses a global `header.php` file, which is pulled from all pages on my website using the `<?php require` function.

I need to use `canonical` tags, but I can't just use one in the global header, because the other pages on my website obviously have different URL's.

Is there a way to solve this, or an alternative solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

#### header.php:

```
<?php
//...

if(isset($canonical_url)){
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="'. htmlspecialchars($canonical_url) .'" />';
}

//...
```

website files that have `require('header.php')`:

```
<?php
//...
$canonical_url = "http://canonical-url.com";
require('header.php');
//...
?>
```

The trick is to define a variable that contains the canonical URL, before the `require` of the header file, and in the `header.php` file, print the tag with the URL previously defined.

Comment: Where exactly does the variable get set? $can=page1, then how are you getting $can to equal page2 and page3 and page4? I do it by having tidy URLs stored in a database and checking which controller is set in my canonical function. Simply saying the trick is to define a variable isn't really giving an answer, it's keeping you at square 1